# Remove lines at Highcharts JS

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm Django a developer. But I need to use one library. To make your schedule. Library written in JS.
Link - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvLzH.png)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What have you tried?  Please share some examples of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the yAxis grid lines in highcharts, you can use *gridLineColor* property and add the color of the chart background.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', { 
     yAxis: { 
         gridLineColor: '#ffffff' //added white color to gridLines
    }
});
```

[check fiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/0t4b1mgw/)